What grounds does my question have for being closed?
I don't think my question warrants being closed for depending on individual circumstances.
It doesn't depend on supervisor's preferences, university, or rules. I am just asking for general feedback on what decisions inform deciding a PhD topic. It could be selective to anyone who is answering based on how they decided. The whole point should be to ask personal questions about academia. If you can only ask factual questions then nothing personal could be asked, and it is useless to have a community group for academia.
Meanwhile, posts that are about academic loneliness are approved. How is that any less dependent on individual circumstances? If you cannot ask a question where there is at least some personal aspect where do you draw the line?
General Advice for Deciding a PhD Experiment?

We tend to frown on questions about picking research topics, they do depend far too much on the individual involved even if you insist otherwise. We also frown on questions asking for open-ended lists.

Isn't the topic of the question one of those things that people enter graduate programs to learn?

There isn’t some personal aspect in that question. There is an unbounded number of personal aspects in that question.
It currently asks for any factors worth considering in deciding a PhD topic. By not specifying these things, it asks this for any person in any domain in any circumstances.
Answers would be about an arbitrary combination of choices for each, and the applicability would depend on whether those happen to match your case.

Note that the "strongly depending on individual factors" close reason is about unknown individual factors. You might be able to salvage the question by specifying some of these so that answers don’t strongly depend on guessing them.
